# Android: make an auto-updated listview with processes

Tags: android, listview

I want to make a listview where I will show the running processes. The command for find the processes is `getSystemService(getActivity().ACTIVITY_SERVICE).getRunningAppProcesses()` where it returns an arraylist with the processes. My question is how to update the listview when a process is closed. I managed to implement this with a Thread(the code below) but I'm not sure how efficient is this. Any other idea?

**Thread code**

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (true) {
                    wait(2500);

                    procs.clear();
                    ramProcs.clear();
                    procs.addAll(manager.getRunningAppProcesses());
                    Iterator itr = procs.iterator();
                    while (itr.hasNext()) {
                        ramProcs.add(manager.getProcessMemoryInfo(new int[]{((ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo) (itr.next())).pid})[0].getTotalPss() * 0.001);
                    }
                    System.gc();
                    if (procs.size() == ramProcs.size()) {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                            public void run() {
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: You should not call the garbage collector ever, as it freezes the thread and notifyDataSetChanged should come right after any changes to the data set. Create a separate Service thread that checks for new data, then add data with adapter.add and immediately call notify.

Comment: Ok but what if I want to update continuously the list because I want to show and the Memory consumed by every process every moment?

Comment: Android should have hooks for those based on other apps doing this and testing tools that do just that. Isn't there something along the lines of a StateChangeListener for processes?